# Necessary conditions for $ X $ to be a Killing field for the metric $g$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

We consider the vector field $X =h(y)∂x$. Give the necessary conditions for $ X $ to be a Killing field for the metric $g$ with
$$g=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1+y^{2} & x y \\
x y & 1+x^{2}
\end{array}\right)
$$

---

$X$ is a Killing field iff  $L_X g=0 ,$ a.e: $$ L_X g(\partial_i,\partial_j)=X(g(\partial_i,\partial_j)) -g([X,\partial_i], \partial_j)-g(\partial_i, [X,\partial_j])$$

\begin{cases}
L_X g(\partial_1,\partial_1)=X(g(\partial_1,\partial_1)) =0 \\
L_X g(\partial_1,\partial_2)=yh(y)-h'(y)(1+y^2)=0\\
L_X g(\partial_2,\partial_2)=2xh(y)-2h'(y)xy=0 \\
\end{cases}
$\iff$

\begin{cases}
h(y)= C\sqrt{1+y^2} \\ h(y)=Dy
\end{cases}

Comment: Can you show your calculation?

Comment: I have edited the post! Can you please see where's the problem?

Comment: Your computations look correct to me (note however that from the differential equations you should get $h(y)=C\sqrt{1+y^2}$ and $h(y)=Dy$ for arbitrary constants, not that it solves the contradiction...)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but how the existence of constants solves the contradiction ?